# How to get file input variables in $(document).ready(function(e){

Tags: jquery

I am trying to upload PDF documents using AJAX, and updating a database with the file name and a "app_id" reference, but don't know how to get the extra variables from the  code.

Here's the jquery code:

I have tried a few different ways of getting the data to the query $(document).ready(function(e) code but it keeps returning as "undefined".

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$("#fupForm").change('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var creditapp_column = $('#creditapp_column').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'upload1.php?column='+creditapp_column+'&app_id=123',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
            $('#fupForm').css("opacity",".5");
        },
        success: function(msg){
            $('.statusMsg').html('');
            if(msg == 'ok'){
                $('#fupForm')[0].reset();
                $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#34A853">Form data submitted successfully.</span>');
            }else{
                $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#EA4335">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
            }
            $('#fupForm').css("opacity","");
            $(".submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});

//file type validation
$("#file").change(function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var imagefile = file.type;
    var match= ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
    if(!((imagefile==match[0]) || (imagefile==match[1]) || (imagefile==match[2]))){
        alert('Please select a valid image file (JPEG/JPG/PNG).');
        $("#file").val('');
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

I want to have the following additional variables to be added to the file upload:  name="creditapp_supplied" creditapp_id='.$results[$k]["app_id"].'

Comment: Get the data inside the submit handler. I don't see what the issue is. *Before* that they won't be filled unless you explicitly give them a value.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:- I was asked to provide a solution for posting the file when it is selected and not when the person clicks the submit button. This is how you would do it.

```
//Store this globally
const AcceptedFileTypes = ["image/jpeg","image/png","image/jpg"];
//file type validation
$("#file").change(function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    if(!AcceptedFileTypes.includes(file.type)){
        alert('Please select a valid image file (JPEG/JPG/PNG).');
        $("#file").val('');
        //You don't really want to return false, that's obtrusive.
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload1.php?column='+creditapp_column+'&app_id=123',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                //You might also want to show a preloader of some kind.
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('#fupForm').css("opacity",".5");
            },
        }).done(function(data){
            //Do something after the success response
        }).fail(function(error){
            //Do something id the request fails.
        });
    }
});
```

There is a bug in the line where you're adding the submit event handler to the form. Change it from.

```
$("#fupForm").change('submit',function(e){//Your code});
```

to

```
$("#fupForm").on('submit',function(e){//Your code});
```

`.change('event name', [handler callback])` is improper syntax, .change binds the change event of the form(which is not where is should be binded) with the handler callback provided. What you are looking for is either `.submit([handler callback])` or `.on("submit", [handler callback])`.

Comment: I don't use a submit button and want it to automatically upload as soon as the file has been loaded.